# Floating EditText on top of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, position, android-edittext, xamarin

In Xamarin, is it possible to have an EditText "floating" on top of a Layout?

I am thinking of a "Bring to front" sort of code.

Currently the EditText is not showing.

Here is my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="49.1dp"
    android:hint="Find..."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15.2dp" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: pls attach screen shot what u exactly want

Comment: Are you sure this is your complete layout file code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place your edittext below frame layout

```
<FrameLayout ... /> <Edittext .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the below property of your `FrameLayout`

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/inputSearch" /> <---- Change it to the id of EditText
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using the RelativeLayout so you have to provide the layout property 
to let know the views where to place them.

So use the layout_below, layout_above, layout_alignParentTop="true" etc to the views 
your using.

Now your **FrameLayout** covers up the whole screen area, just apply the
layout_alignParentTop="true" to your edit text view and 
layout_below with the edittext view id to the FrameLayout. will resolve your problem.